# how to run different classes.....starting at the same time

Tags: testing, testng

i ran the following xml in testng and what i found out was that even though the classes are running in different threads they are running sequentially.....meaning the 1st class "HP" is run and then then the 2nd class "copyofHp" starts to run.

Eclipse: Juno service release 1
TestNG plugin: 6.8

ANyway both the classes can be executed in parallel .....starting at the same time?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

   <suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
     <test name="FHP" parallel="classes" thread-count="5" junit="true">
       <classes>
         <class name="HP"></class>
         <class name="CopyOfHP"></class>
       </classes>
     </test>
   </suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not correct but its working for my purpose.

But i would be grateful if someone can show how to get it working from class level rather than test level...

```
 <suite name="Suite1" parallel="tests" thread-count="5" verbose="1" >
 <test name="FHPA"  junit="true">
 <classes>
  <class name="FHP"></class> 
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="FHPB" junit="true">
  <classes>
  <class name="CopyFHP"></class>
      </classes>
  </test>
 </suite>
```